# What's the best way to detect the start of a session (similar to Global.ashx's Session_Start) when using ServiceStack SessionFeature?

Tags: session, servicestack, session-state

I've enabled Sessions support in service stack like:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => container.Resolve<PooledRedisClientManager>());
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

//RE: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions
Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
```

I see that ss-id and ss-pidd cookies are set upon visiting the site, however I would like to know when a session is started (i.e., first request from that user) so i can capture the incoming referrer url.

Using traditional asp.net sessions, i'd use Session_Start in Global, however this doesn't fire for me while using SS sessions.

Is there a good way to detect this session start event when using ServiceStack?  I didn't find any reference in my queries online, or on the [ServiceStack Sessions wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no "Session Started" event in ServiceStack's Sessions feature, but there are some events on [IAuthSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/IAuthSession.cs#L30-L32) that might be useful to use instead, e.g:

```
public interface IAuthSession
{
    ...
    void OnRegistered(IServiceBase registrationService);
    void OnLogout(IServiceBase authService);
    void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, 
         IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo);
}
```

If you still would like to see an OnSessionStarted event request it as a feature in [ServiceStack's GitHub issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open) (and include your use-case), so we can keep track of it.

Comment: So no events on the Session itself, only if using the Authentication features?

Comment: Right, there are currently no Session events. You can always implement your own [SessionFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/SessionFeature.cs) plugin and just use that instead.

Comment: Sounds good.  If I come up with a clean implementation I'll submit a pull request.  Assuming this is something you see value in having in the default SessionFeature plugin, right?

Comment: @JesseP yep, that's the beauty of OSS: Add once, benefit all :)

Comment: one more question...  Does servicestack honor the (or absence of) web.config sessionState enable/disable configuration?

Comment: Nope, ServiceStack is completely de-coupled from any of ASP.NET's existing membership, caching or session providers - we only use clean-slate replacements.